# Acces To Individual Property Of List<T>datastructure of a class in WPF

Tags: wpf, list

i have a `List<T>`
of a class like

```
public class info
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string Depname { get; set; }
}

List<info> query=(from c in student join Dep in Department
    on c.studentid equals in.Studentid                   
    select new info 
    {
        id=c.studentid,
        Depname=in.Depname
    } ).ToList;
```

what i want is i want to access the property name like Depname as

```
string SDepname=query.Depname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer using Select and FirstOrDefault

```
var SDepname = query.Select(x => x.Depname).FirstOrDefault()
```

SDepname will be the first Depname in the query or null if no records found.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
 srting SDepname=query.Depname;
```

but `query` is a `List<>` so the question would be : which element?  There could be 0, 1 or more candidates.

Closest you can get:

```
 string SDepname=query.First().Depname;    // throws on empty result set
```

or maybe

```
 string (SDepname=query.FirstOrDefault() ?? new Info { Depname = "" }).Depname;
```

Comment: or `SDepname = query.Select(x => x.Depname).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: thanks a lot @Bob Vale it is working but as you have not answer u have just comment on it so how can i check your answer.

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib I've created an answer